# nuxt3: how to test SSR page with form, useFetch() and pinia?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vitest

In my Nuxt3 project, I have a very basic login page which is SSR like the following:

**pages/login.vue**

```js
<template>
    <form
        @submit.prevent="login">
        <input
            name="email"
            v-model="form.email"/>
        <input
            name="password"
            v-model="form.password"/>
        <button>login</button>
    <form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useAuth } from '~/store/auth.js'; 

const auth = useAuth();
const form = ref({email: '', password: ''});
const router = useRouter();

const login = async () => {
    useFetch('/api/auth/tokens', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form.value
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
          const { token, user } =  data.value;
          auth.setUser(user);
          auth.setToken(token);
          router.push('/profile');           
    })
}
</script>
```

---

1. First, I try to test it like a SPA page:

```js
import { describe, test, expect } from 'vitest';
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import LoginPage from '~/pages/login.vue';

describe('login page', async () => {

    test('store tokens', async () => {

        const wrapper = mount(LoginPage);

        const email = 'test@example.com';
        const password = 'password';

        await wrapper.find('[name="email"]').setValue(email);
        await wrapper.find('[name="password"]').setValue(password);

        await wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit.prevent');

        expect(
            wrapper.emitted('submit')[0][0]
        ).toStrictEqual({
            email,
            password,
        });

        // But this does not test the code in `then()` which handled the response and redirect to `/profile`
    });
});
```

Got error:

> FAIL  tests/pages/login.spec.js > login page > store tokens
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
> [image: document is not defined]

2. Then, I followed the [Nuxt3 testing](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/testing#setup)

```js
import { describe, test, expect } from 'vitest';
import { setup, $fetch } from '@nuxt/test-utils';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

describe('login page', async () => {

    await setup();

    test('store tokens', async () => {

        const wrapper = (new JSDOM(await $fetch('/login'))).window.document;

        const email = 'test@example.com';
        const password = 'password';

        await wrapper.find('[name="email"]').setValue(email);
        await wrapper.find('[name="password"]').setValue(password);

        await wrapper.find('form').trigger('submit.prevent');

        expect($fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/api/auth/tokens', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                email: 'test@example.com',
                password: 'password'
            }
        });
        
    });
});
```

But `wrapper` there is just a jsdom document instance, it can't act like a Vue component.

---

I wonder:

1. How to test the user input events?
2. How to test the code in `resovle` of `useFetch()` (in the example, it's the code handling data with pinia)

*same question in [GitHub](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/15938)*

Answer (score 1):

I would unit test the component, so check if inputs work as expected and also if the correct action is triggered on submit. So don't render a whole page, just mount the component in the test.

I would test the `login` action afterwards separately meaning you mock the data from the API (token, user) and check if they are set correctly to the `auth`. Plus, if there's a redirect. This should be possible.

You want to test the whole feature (login) which is often referred as "feature testing". But the base is unit tests.

Comment: Do you mean I should test the SSR and function of the page component separately instead of testing it in a single `test()` function? Would you like to share the test code of your idea? (Some code I already done to test the user input event in [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-q6hne6-trebwi?file=test/form.test.js))

Comment: I gave you the bounty since you're the only one who answered, but I would really appreciate it if any shared code

Comment: @DengSihan exactly. first you test if your component works how it should. it doesn't matter if it is SSR or not. you could then extend your testing. next3 testing uses `playwright` under the hood (see "browser" setting) which you can use for a feature test like go on page X, expect a headline/form/etc to be there, fill in some form, press submit, expect response (like beeing redirected, having a success flash/notice or errors on input fields, etc, etc). see playwright docs, https://playwright.dev/docs/writing-tests